# Coordinates not displaying in UTM

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, utm

Mac OS 10.9.5; QGIS 2.8.4-Wien; offending data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hqa54vh7x1m6pd/vic_bfire_omeo_union_p.zip?dl=0)

I want to calculate the centroid of a polygon in meters. However, I cannot get QGIS to display in UTM and I cannot transform/project the data to UTM. I followed instructions on a number of answers to similar questions (e.g. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114561/how-to-display-distance-in-meters-km-and-not-in-decimal-degrees-in-qgis-2-4), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13023/how-to-change-the-unit-of-measure-from-degrees-to-meters-in-qgis) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30484/problem-with-spatial-reference-system-shapefile-projection)) and still have the data displaying in lat/longs (in the coordinate box at the bottom of the main screen).

In Project Properties/CRS I have set the project properties to UTM GDA94 / MGA zone 55, checked 'Enable on the fly' CRS transformations. In Project Properties/General/Canvas units I have selected Meters.

I added the vector data and defined current projection under Vector/Data Management Tools. I projected the data to UTM GDA94 / MGA zone 55 and saved the layer in that CRS. When I did this, the extent of the layer was showing in lat/longs, not meters. I've also tried to do this in a couple of other projected coordinate systems (WGS 84 / UTM zone 55S and GDA94 / Geoscience Australia Lambert) and am having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data appears to be in WGS84 CRS. Telling it that it's in some other meter grid is not how to work with it.
I defined it's CRS as WGS84 [EPSG:4326], as well as redefined my map CRS to it and it appears coherent with Australia (indeed the default was UTM GDA94 / MGA zone 55 [EPSG:28355]).

[image]
Then I exported it as a new layer with the GDA94 CRS.

In order to avoid any unknown bug, I have a habit of always rebooting my GIS program when working with different CRS. I then opened the new layer, and it opened correctly.
See image, and note the CRS.
[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clear instructions. I followed this method and it is now displaying in metres.

Comment: Thanks HDunn. It did work and I just up voted it. I couldn't do that earlier because I only had 6 rep points. Is there something else I need to so to accept it? I'm new to this site so still learning the etiquette.

Answer (score 3):

`Define current projection` is the wrong tool. Your data is in degrees, and you better leave it that way (or put it back to it before working further).

Use `Save As ...` to reproject the data to another filename and CRS, like UTM or Lambert.